# Unable to exclude directory /System on Mac while using find command to scan / directory

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, macos

I was trying to scan entire Mac for finding files greater than 1GB. I couldn't stop the `find` command from scanning directories `/System` and `/System/Volumes`.

```
find -x / -type f -size +1G
```

I tried `prune`, `! -path`, `-not -path` and nothing seems to help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the commands you tried that didn't work. The syntax is a bit tricky so we would need to see them to understand what went wrong.

Comment: Are you using [tag:zsh] or [tag:bash]? Please update your tags.

Comment: @MarlonRichert, presumably the OP is looks for an answer giving code in the syntax of either shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find -x / -path /System -prune -or -type f -size +1G -print
```

Getting boolean logic right for `find` is, IMO, one of the hardest things about the program - without using parentheses, it's easy to lose track of the logic...and it doesn't help at all that having to escape parentheses makes it ugly and difficult to read.

In short: the key thing you have to remember about find is that every predicate is **implicitly ANDed** with the previous predicate(s) unless you tell `find` to use OR (`-or` or `-o`).

AND is `-and` or `-a`, but as AND is the default you rarely need to use AND explicitly, unless you want to make it explicitly clear so it's easier to understand when you need to edit it in X months time when you've forgotten how it works again.  e.g. the following is equivalent to the example above:

```
find -x / -path /System -and -prune -or -type f -and -size +1G -print
```

They're both evaluated like: `(-path /System -and -prune) -or (-type f -and -size +1G)`

So the command above ANDs `-path /System` and `-prune`, then ORs that with `-type f` AND `-size +1G`, resulting in the /System directory and all sub-directories (so there's no need to explicitly exclude /System/Volumes) being excluded from the search.

If you need to exclude two or more directories, use parentheses, which need to be escaped or quoted to hide their special (i.e. compound-command / sub-shell) meaning from bash. For example:

```
find -x / \( -path /System -o -path /somewhere -o -path /else \) -prune -o -type f -size +1G -print
```

In this example, the `-prune` applies to directories `(/System OR /somewhere OR /else)`

I hope that clarifies things a little - I'm a bit sleep-deprived at the moment, and am not sure if I've explained that well or not.

BTW, that `-x` option from FreeBSD's find is a good enhancement.  Using the standard `-xdev` predicate, further complicates the boolean logic.  (Unfortunately, GNU find doesn't have `-x`, but that's not relevant to you since you're running on a Mac which uses FreeBSD's `find`)

Comment: Trying to find the history of those `-and` / `-or` alternatives for `-a` / `-o`, I just realised BSD had initially experimented with [a new syntax with predicates without the leading `-`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/34e4fa5b7ff1dcfeb975b714569b671976eb5e3b), so hence `and` and `or` there. That was [eventually reverted](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/0299efb49c3951ccc43d4bfcd7933382acbb9754), but the `and` became `-and` at that point ([later](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/5e7c98d7bdab9d81eaa2deb76f68ad94e3450b47).

Comment: GNU `find` already had `-and` and `-or`  as alternatives to `-a`/`-o` in 3.1 in 1991 but the changelog doesn't mention when they were added, so I don't know if it came from GNU or BSD.

Comment: SysV-based `find`s, `sfind` still only support `-a`/`-o`, the only ones specified by POSIX.